# Gitlab job is successful despite assertion failure

Tags: maven, gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I am running SoapUI assertions using maven image in gitlab. Even though the assertion fails the build is successful in gitlab. I have tried using mvn integration-tests -ff and as well as -fae but no luck. Also used allow_failure: false. This did not work either. Please advise as to how to fail the gitlab pipeline job if there is a failure in assertions.

Here is my yml file

```
T001-0011:
  extends: .ETE -stage
  image: adoptopenjdk/maven-openjdk11
  variables:
   MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "--fail-fast"
  script:
  - 'mvn -f ./TV001/pom.xml $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS integration-test'
  allow_failure: false
     
  when: always
```

Here is the gitlab log

```
   1 error
    09:53:48,937 ERROR [SoapUITestCaseRunner] JDBC_Request failed, exporting to [/builds/gitlab/data/test-team-automation-scripts/./SV321/Warnings/target/surefire-reports/TestSuite_1-AC1-JDBC_Request-0-FAILED.txt]
    09:53:48,938 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [AC1], time taken: 904ms, status: FAILED
    09:53:48,953 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Running SoapUI testcase [AC2]
    09:53:48,963 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] running step [IDN220001-Request2]
    09:53:48,966 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Stale connection check
    09:53:48,968 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Attempt 1 to execute request
    09:53:48,968 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Sending request: GET /apikey/v1/warnings/waning/IDN22000 HTTP/1.1
    09:53:48,974 DEBUG [SoapUIMultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager$SoapUIDefaultClientConnection] Receiving response: HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
    09:53:48,975 DEBUG [HttpClientSupport$SoapUIHttpClient] Connection can be kept alive indefinitely
    09:53:49,018 INFO  [log] HTTP status code: 404
    09:53:49,019 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [Valid HTTP Status Codes] has status UNKNOWN
    09:53:49,019 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Assertion [Script Assertion] has status VALID
    09:53:49,019 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Finished running SoapUI testcase [AC2], time taken: 8ms, status: FINISHED
    09:53:49,021 INFO  [SoapUITestCaseRunner] Project [DPD-3396] finished with status [FAILED] in 2591ms
    SoapUI 5.3.0 TestCaseRunner Summary
    -----------------------------
    Time Taken: 2599ms
    Total TestSuites: 1
    Total TestCases: 2 (1 failed)
    Total TestSteps: 3
    Total Request Assertions: 5
    Total Failed Assertions: 1
    Total Exported Results: 3

[WARNING] JAR will be empty - no content was marked for inclusion!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  03:03 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2022-06-15T09:53:54+10:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Cleaning up file based variables
00:01
Job succeeded
```

Comment: I see you’ve attempted to reply to tolis by editing the answer. Please use comments, or if your question needs clarifying, edit your own question, rather than responding in an edit to an answer. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry about that

Comment: No worries! The rules of the site take some getting used to. Thanks for asking!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mvn tests fail but the exit code that the command itself returns, probably is zero.

It is saying, I managed to run the tests.
But for you this doesn't help since you want to check the result of the tests.

Gitlab in order to fail a job checks the exit code of the commands used. You could force mvn to return an erroneous exit code when the tests fail

You could add the following flag

```
-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false
```

Comment: apologies for editing your response. As per your advise, I have tried as per the above. Still no luck. Please advise

Comment: Will update the answer promptly